Terraform "strcontains" not working, is this "strcontains" correct?
When I trying to using tf strcontains to find the sub string on given string getting below exception.
> There is no function named "strcontains".
on data.tf line 46, in data "aws_security_group" "sgs_for_lambda":
  46:   

name = strcontains(var.nstance, "prod") && var.domain_name == "deploy" ? "${var.domain_name}_prod_restricted_${var.domain_name}_extended" : strcontains(var.nstance, "dev") ? "${var.domain_name}_dev_restricted_${var.domain_name}_extended" : "${var.domain_name}_prod_processing_${var.domain_name}_extended"


Which terraform version are you using?

What is the actual code and values of the variables resulting in the error?

terraform -v
Terraform v0.13.7

Nothing is resulting because of this error:
There is no function named "strcontains". on

The strcontains function was added in v1.5.0: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/releases/tag/v1.5.0: "Adds a new strcontains function that checks whether a given string contains a given substring. (#33069)" If you are indeed on v0.13.7, your TF version is too old.

You can run : terraform -v
and check on the terraform docs if version that you have support this function
Link to the docs (you must select your version) : https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.4.x
For example the version 1.4.X does not support strcontains

strcontains function is only available in the Terraform version v1.5.x and after.
Check this below link to find it.
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.5.x/functions/strcontains
